# Visual Studio Could Not Reformat Line Due To Nested Image Tag in Achor Tag

Tags: html, visual-studio

When I try to reformat Visual Studio complains about a nested image tag I have in my html:

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 1480px">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"> //complains about this line.
                        <img src="images/myLogo.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

The link and image work fine, but I was wondering where I may have written some bad html since Visual Studio refuses to reformat, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using single-quotes `'` instead of double-quotes `"` for your `href` attribute :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 1480px">
            <a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'>
                <img src="images/myLogo.png" alt="" />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This changes appears to be free of complaint in Visual Studio 2015 locally :

[image]

Double-quotes can often throw off the Razor View engine at times as it thinks that you are trying to write some C# inside of it.

Comment: Yes, worked like a charm on my end. Tysm this was driving me nuts!!